# Play a live, arbitrary waveform through speakers

Tags: c#

I have a C# program that currently generates a wave based on a formula entered into a parser - the wave can be anything, from a simple sine wave to a noise function. I want to play the wave *as it generates* through the speakers. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: This would take a little finagling but it could be done with NAudio, Google that and get started with it, then if you have specific questions about it post a very specific question (with code).

Comment: You should generate PCM signal by your function http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation then you can play that signal in many ways including standard .net ways.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a best place for posting question not about a code. Try to search specific site on StackExchange.

Answer (score 1):

Consider generating your waveform and then using NAudio or DirectSound to play it back.